# Mysql -> joinin two rows in output

Tags: mysql

My table consist of this below

```
Country   | Type     |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   | cType
------------------------------------------------------------------
Italy     | Foreign  |       |       |   C   |   D   | Commercial  
Italy     | Foreign  |   A   |   B   |       |       | Commercial
Italy     | Local    |       |       |   C   |   D   | Gov
Italy     | Local    |   A   |   B   |       |       | Gov
```

I want to do a query that out put the result like below, using the type

```
Italy   | Foreign  |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   | Commercial
Italy   | Local    |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   | GOV
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select country, type, max(A), max(B), max(C), max(D), cType
from whatever_table
group by country, type, cType
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Im still trying to get my head round using mysql, How do i accept this as the answer

Comment: after a sufficient waiting time (i think it is 20min) you can click on that check mark to the left of my answer

Comment: A group_concat() would be better. Max() only will take 1 of the options in each column

Comment: hi How would that work then, cause i tried it but the result would not come out the way i wanteds

Comment: try to add some more specification of what you want. the query above achieves what you stated, but both max() and group_concat() are a wild guess on what you actually want to do. maybe you can enlighten us about the purpose of all the A, B, C and Ds. Also, are the empty fields NULL or empty strings? What is the meaning of it all, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: My query fields is base on rating system on with the column i miss out by mistake that column contains local or company, so when i output it through php,

Comment: still no idea. if the A, B, C and D columns are to be treated the same way, why not throw away B, C and D for the purpose of the  example, and instead explain WHY the desired output contains the value "A" in each row. is it a sum? an average? a list of strings? please edit your question accordingly